# Confusion of measuring the stator voltage of induction motor

Tags: inverter, voltage-measurement, induction-motor, stator

I'm new to inverters and the only way I know how to measure the stator voltage of induction motor is to connect the multimeter to terminal of junction box. So could anybody please elaborate more about the way [this paper](https://theses.ncl.ac.uk/jspui/bitstream/10443/3232/1/Alturas%2c%20A.M.%202016.pdf) is getting the stator voltage of an induction motor? I have attached an excerpt below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case modulation index is defined as

\$m=V_{out peak}/V_{DClink}\$

Which means if one knows \$m\$ and \$V_{DClink}\$, the calculation of \$V_{out peak}\$ is trivial and that value is the applied stator voltage. Note that being a peak value there may be some wayward 1.4’s or 0.707’s to convert to RMS as need be, plus all the customary \$\sqrt{3}\$’s if this is a three phase system.